# How to Unset the shipping method from quote in magento 2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, magento2.3

I need to unset the shipping method if it was selected by the customer based on some condition. I tried

> $('#shipping_method').prop('checked', false);

unchecking the radio button of that particular shipping method but the shipping method is set and shipping charges is applied to the cart.

How to unset the shipping method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it myself. We can unset the shipping method like below:

```
require([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method'    
   ],
    function(
        selectShippingMethodAction
    ) {
        selectShippingMethodAction(null)  //pass on the shippingmethod
    });
```